# Error occur when upgrading to Sonar to 4.2

Tags: sonarqube

After upgrading to Sonar to 4.2, I have errors on some projects with these logs :
The resource '...' is duplicated in database
I had to manually remove the duplicate lines in the database as i didn't know what is the snapshot that provokes this behavior, or if it's du to Database upgrade.
Hope to understand what has going on as i should upgrade other Sonar servers to version 4.2

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing relates to a bug that we're currently investigating. Follow the following thread of discussion to get some news about the fix : http://sonar.markmail.org/thread/rgpwforpxm6elnc7

Comment: Actually, 4.2 is meant to be a "stable" version. The upgrade provoked a lot of maintenance on the database. Is there a way to "clean" the database to get rid of these duplicates, wiating for the fix? Is there a bug issue in sonarqube jira.codehaus database?

Comment: JIRA ticket created but we're still trying to reproduce this issue locally : https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5233. Could you also answer the questions asked by Julien Henry on the mailing list : http://markmail.org/message/yu2nmqnlr24st3ir? Thanks

Comment: For the question "Do you face the same issue if you start to analyze the very same project
from scratch?", the answer is no. I face the issue only for projects inherited from previous Sonar bench.

Comment: For the question "Do you remember the version of SQ Java that was installed on your SQ 4.1 instance? 1.5 ? 2.0 ?" the answer is Java plugin version 1.5

Comment: And why is my question is rated -1 ?